# Simplify integral using partial fractions

Tags: calculus, integration

If $I = \int x^{3}\sin x\mathrm{d}x$, how do I simplify this using partial fractions? Simplify not calculate. I chose $v=x^{3}$ and got $\frac{1}{3} x^{4}\sin x-\frac{1}{3} \int x^{3} \sin x+ x^{4} \cos x\mathrm{d}x$

Comment: You mean integration **by parts** ? Partial fractions is entirely different

Answer (score 1):

$v=x^3$ and $du=\sin x\,dx \Rightarrow dv=3x^2\,dx$ and $u=-\cos x$

$\int v\, du=uv-\int u\, dv \Rightarrow \int x^{3}\sin x\, dx=-x^3\cos x +\int 3x^2\cos x\, dx$

$\int 3x^2\cos x dx=3x^2\sin x-\int 6 x \sin x\, dx$

$\int 6 x \sin x\, dx=6 x \cos x-\int 6 \cos x\, dx=6 x \cos x - 6 \sin x$

After this point, all you have to do is plug last integral to other equations.